# In virtual-machine Docker push to private registry failed under proxy

Tags: docker, proxy, virtual-machine

I want to push a Docker image to a private registry in the local machine.

The docker is running in a virtual-machine CentOS 7 and I'm working a in a network under a proxy.

What I did is to tag my Docker local image "test_bench_image" obtained from building a dockerfile:

```
docker tag test_bench_image localhost:5000/test_bench_image
```

and then I tried to push it:

```
 docker push localhost:5000/test_bench_image
```

What I get is:

```
The push refers to a repository [localhost:5000/test_bench_image]
Put http://localhost:5000/v1/repositories/test_bench_image/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: getsockopt: connection refused
```

I understood that /etc/sysconfig/docker should include the variable no_proxy to allow pushing to private Docker registry under a proxy. So I included in the file:

```
...
http_proxy="http://myproxy.es:80"
https_proxy="http://myproxy.es:80"
no_proxy="127.0.0.1:5000"
```

But I get the same error message after reload the daemon and restart the docker service.

Any help will be really welcome.

*Note: My original plan was to use the Docker local image in Jenkins. But the Docker plugin cannot pull the local image since it is not publicly available. So I tried to create a private registry and force Jenkins to pull it from there.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and I had to additionally uncomment and add my private registry's host IP in the section INSECURE_REGISTRY='XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5000' in /etc/sysconfig/docker file.